# AsymmetricGridView With a CusorAdapter?

Tags: android, gridview, cursor, android-cursoradapter

Has anyone succeeded in using [AsymmetricGridView](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView) with a cursorAdapter as a basis for the gridview content? Could you provide an example?

There's something similar as to what I'd like to accomplish [here](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView/issues/16) but I'm unsure what to replace 'JCell' with.

Comment: It seems to work, see [related issue and commit](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView/issues/16). What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use RecyclerView with StaggeredGridLayoutManager instead of "AsymmetricGridView".
[Try with this example](http://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/)